# What is the output of following program in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What is the output of this program and explain it to me please?

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#define     foo(m,n)    m##n
int     main()
{
     printf("%s\n",foo(k,l));
}
```

Comment: Why not try [compiling it and see for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c1bbe66c171de7b) ?

Comment: @PaulR Because it won't compile, I guess..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: sure, but at least the warnings and error messages would be instructive.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to compile this program I got this error
`[Error] 'kl' was not declared in this scope`

Actually, 
**the ## operator takes two separate tokens and pastes them together to form a single token.** The resulting token could be a variable name, class name or any other identifier.

So here you are trying to print a identifier "kl" without even declaring it. Now just add this line

`char kl[16]="hello world!";`

You will get the output **hello world!**

Comment: @KSrinivasPavanKumar.: No need to thanks...if it fulfills your need accept it.